# How can I get the color of a pixel on screen with Node.js or C?

Tags: node.js, c, linux, x11

I am trying to get the color of a pixel on my screen using node.js. I want it to be returned in RGB format, e.g. (255, 0, 0). My current solution is to use `screenshot-desktop` to screenshot my entire screen in JPG format, decode it to get the raw pixel data, and get the color of a given pixel. However, this lags out my entire computer for 1-2 seconds as it is taking the screenshot. This is unusable as I would like to do this multiple times per second. So my question is: How can I get the color of a given pixel on the screen, without taking a full screenshot?

I am using Linux with X11. There is an X11 library for node.js, so I asssume I should use that to get the pixel color, I'm just not sure how. If you could show me how to do it in C then I can easily use node.js to do the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

X11 solution using `x11` node library ( I am the author ):

- query windows tree with QueryTree starting at the root window
- get every child geometry using GetGeometry request
- if your point is *not* inside any child, use current window id and get 1x1 pixmap from the current image: `GetImage(format, currentWindow, x, y, 1, 1, planeMask)` ( 2 for format and 0xffffffff for plane mask should work ). Make sure you calculate relative x y position as you travers windows tree.
- if child window covers your point query children for that window and repeat again. Note that QueryTree returns windows in bottom to top stacking order so make sure you pick last one covering your point

Once you have 1x1 pixmap from the topmost window under your point - the buffer should contain only color bytes for your image, RGB order and bit mask might depend on `red_mask`, `green_mask`, `blue_mask` from `display.screen[0].depths[visual]`.

If you cache "topmost window" between requests and only start from root when no match anymore the above solution might be much more performant then the one using `robotjs` ( although much more low level and complicated ) Good luck!

Comment: If composite manager is used ( which is most likely in 2022 ) you can get the drawable associated with the overlay window and the rest is just a 1x1 GetImage request to that window

Answer (score 1):

Oh my gosh I just figured it out after posting this. I was using `robotjs` for reading the mouse position and I totally forgot it can do screen stuff too! So, the solution would be to do

```
var robot = require('robotjs');
var color = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
```

Comment: The only problem is many screens use 125% resolution or something of the sort which misaligns the cursor position and the screen color positions